# Windsor PerWebRequestLifestyleModule - registered, but still getting error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-windsor

I receive the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll

Additional information: Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule

To fix this add

<add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />

to the <httpModules> section on your web.config.

Windsor also detected you're running IIS in Integrated Pipeline mode. This means that you also need to add the module to the <modules> section under <system.webServer>.

Alternatively make sure you have Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 assembly in your GAC (it is installed by ASP.NET MVC3 or WebMatrix) and Windsor will be able to register the module automatically without having to add anything to the config file.
```

This has just started happening since I updated a load of NuGet references (incl Windsor, Web API, etc), and updated all the projects to .NET 4.5.1.

Whether I have the module listed and registered in `<system.web>` or `<system.webServer>` under the appropriate section, the message still appears.

Note that the Web API project in question here also references `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure`, the correct version, and obviously this doesn't make a difference either.

(I didn't have to have the module listed in web.config before - but now, whether I list it in either section, both or none, referencing that helper assembly or not, I get this message).

What can I do to diagnose?

Comment: What version of Windsor to and from? Make sure you don't have the .NET 4.0 Client Profile build, but the .NET 4.5 one as the client profile build doesn't have the auto-registration code. This is how it works, you could try adding this code to your app to test it still works with upgraded dependencies: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Lifestyle/PerWebRequestLifestyleModuleRegistration.cs

Comment: Thanks - in fact I didn't change Windsor version; 3.3.0 (net45 build) in both cases.  I tried that code, of course it wants to be called before Application_Start though; but when I try `PreApplicationStartMethod`, the pointed-to method simply isn't called (no exception).  I'm using IIS Express, but can't think that that's the issue - I was using it previously, too..

Comment: Ok, my bad - `[assembly: ...` only valid in AssemblyInfo.cs of course.  The code runs - the `registerModule.Invoke(null, new object[] { typeof(PerWebRequestLifestyleModule) });` definitely runs - but I still get the exception (looks like you forgot to register..)

Comment: Any chance you can provide a repro project? If you don't want to post the link here, my email is "jono" at "my twitter handle" .com. Other than that you'll have to debug the Windsor code to find out why it isn't registering or doesn't think it has actually been registered, or step one by one upgrading a single library at a time.

Comment: Here's a repro! - https://github.com/kierenj/windsor-httpmodule-repro

Comment: (Hoping there's something obvious I missed :))

Comment: Oh, now seeing the code the problem is that you can't resolve a per web request lifestyle component in Application_Start. Logically it doesn't make sense because the request scope doesn't exist, technically it gives you that error because HTTP modules are initialised after Application_Start. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs,2355

Comment: Ugh, thanks - I didn't even twig that I was trying to do that - in fact in my code, the service I want isn't PerWebRequest.  One obscure dependency of it is, however.  That'll do it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Thanks to Jonathon Rossi)

You'll also get this exception if you try to resolve something with the per-web-request lifecycle within `Application_Start`, because the module is registered but not initialised yet.

The fix - don't try to resolve anything scoped in this way in `Application_Start`.

(I suppose the Windsor error message is a little cryptic, assumes something else is going on ;))